# Both shared-memory and distributed-memory

Tags: distributed-systems, parallel-computing

As you see in the following picture its a shared-memory architecture which has been modeled in a form of **complete graph**.
Why we can consider the following architecture (which is a complete graph) **both** as **shared-memory** and **distributed-memory** architecture?

[image]

I know it seems to be an distributed-memory architecture but can we say that if we consider local memory of one of the processor as shared-memory for other ones(I mean the shared-memory is located in one of the processor) then we can consider it as shared-memory architecture not distributed?

Comment: In which context? Who says so?

Comment: parallel-computing

Comment: [Distributed Shared Memory@wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points, but in general the diagram doesn't provide enough information to make any real conclusions.

First, this isn't the typical layout for shared memory architecture. Typically shared memory architecture has a single, shared bank of memory that all processors access. This diagram does not show that type of architecture.

See here:

[image: Shared Memory Architecture]

Second (with regard to not having enough information), the memory isn't shown in this diagram. We don't know whether the processors are accessing memory directly, or just communicating with other processors who in effect access their own private memory. In this case this would be distributed memory architecture. In another case, where a single address space is shared for access to all memory, then this would be distributed shared memory architecture.

Comment: Thanks theoneandonly2. I'm familiar with both architecture but I thinks complete graphs of processors are exception.  I have updated the question to mention my problem exactly that would be great to help.

Comment: If each processor is accessing the memory of the others directly then this would likely be a distributed shared memory architecture.